# I need to do a deep copy, am I using my copy constructor correctly?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, copy-constructor

I need to do a deep copy. Am I using my copy constructor correctly? What should I change?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList
{
    public:
        int data;
        LinkedList* prevNode;

        LinkedList()
        {
            int dd = 0;
            prevNode = nullptr;
        }

        LinkedList(int dd, LinkedList* pr)
        {
            data = dd;
            prevNode = pr;
        }
};

class Stack
{
    private:
        LinkedList* topNode;

    public:
        Stack();
        Stack(const Stack& original);
        ~Stack();

        bool isEmpty() const;
        int top() const;
        int pop();
        void push(int);
};

Stack::Stack()
{
    topNode = nullptr;
}

Stack::Stack(const Stack& original)
{
    this->topNode = original.topNode;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
    {
        pop();
    }
}

bool Stack::isEmpty() const
{
    if (topNode == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int Stack::top() const
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw runtime_error("error: stack is empty");
    }
    return topNode->data;
}

int Stack::pop()
{
    int topVal = top();

    LinkedList* oldtop = topNode;
    topNode = topNode->prevNode;
    return topVal;
}

void Stack::push(int newData)
{
    LinkedList* newNode = new LinkedList(newData, topNode);
    topNode = newNode;
}

int returnNumber(string inputString)
{
    istringstream fr(inputString); 
    int number;

    while (fr >> number)
    { 
        return number;
    }
    if (fr.fail())
    {
        throw runtime_error("error: not a number");
    }

    return number;
}

void list(Stack s)
{
    cout << "[";
    while (!s.isEmpty())
    {
        cout << s.pop();
        if (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            cout << ",";
        }
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;
}

void readCommands(Stack& newStack)
{
    string command = " ";
    while (command != "end")
    {
        cout << "stack> ";
        cin >> command;
        cout << endl;
        if (cin.eof())
        {
            break;
        }

        try 
        {
            if (command == "top")
            {
                cout << newStack.top() << endl;
            }
            else if (command == "pop")
            {
                cout << newStack.pop() << endl;
            }
            else if (command == "push")
            {
                string inputValue;
                cin >> inputValue;

                int number = returnNumber(inputValue);
                newStack.push(number);
                cin.ignore();
            }
            else if (command == "list")
            {
                list(newStack);
            }
            else
            {  
                if (command != "end")
                {
                    throw runtime_error("error: invalid command");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (runtime_error e)
        {
            cout << e.what() << endl;
        } 
    }
}

int main()
{
    Stack newStack;

    readCommands(newStack);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it is doing a shallow copy.  You should do a deep copy.

Comment: This does exactly the same thing, as the compiler generated, default copy-constructor would be doing.

Comment: When you get this working take it for a code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com (needs to work first though).

Comment: For every call to `new` there **must** be a corresponding call to `delete`. I don't see any calls to delete (maybe when you pop an item and don't keep a reference?).

Comment: Please don't delete your question like that! It makes Chipster's answer worthless. I have rolled it back to the previous edit. Instead of saying thank you, you could upvote the answer, and accept it (by clicking on the big tick mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

> I need to do a deep copy, am I using my copy constructor correctly?

No. To do a deep copy, you need to allocate new space in the new stack. That will look something like this:

```
class LinkedList
    {
        public:
             static LinkedList* Copy(LinkedList* c) {
                  if(c == nullptr) {
                       return nullptr;
                  } else {
                      return new LinkedList(data, Copy(prevNode));
                  }
             }
};
```

This static function takes any pointer and creates a copy of its value and its list.

Then, inside your stack:

```
Stack::Stack(const Stack& original)
    {
        this->topNode = LinkedList::Copy(original.topNode);
    }
```

By doing it this way, you are actually creating new memory and not blindly copying the pointer. That's the big idea of deep copies.

If you're still confused on how deep copies work, I'd suggest consulting your textbook or professor.